# summation matrix optimization

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I want to calculate next formula and calculate the q, the problem is as fallow

$$
s = max_{q} \sum_i \frac{q_i^T C_i q_i}{q_i^T B q_i}
$$
$$
st.       Q^TQ = I
$$

where
$q_i$ is Nx1

$C_i$ is rank 1 matrix and it is NxN

and B is positive definite.

Does any one know how $q_i$ can be calculate?

Comment: Have you tied Lagrange multipliers? I doubt there is a analytical solution though.

Comment: a NxN matrix of Lagrange multipliers is needed! I don't think it's the solution. It is look like Jade but the summation!